# Terminating a subprocess with KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, interrupt, terminate

I'm using Python to call a C++ program using the subprocess module. Since the program takes some time to run, I'd like to be able to terminate it using Ctrl+C. I've seen a few questions regarding this on StackOverflow but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

What I would like is for the subprocess to be terminated on KeyboardInterrupt. This is the code that I have (similar to suggestions in other questions):

```
import subprocess

binary_path = '/path/to/binary'
args = 'arguments' # arbitrary

call_str = '{} {}'.format(binary_path, args)

proc = subprocess.Popen(call_str)

try:
    proc.wait()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    proc.terminate()
```

However, if I run this, the code is hung up waiting for the process to end and never registers the KeyboardInterrupt. I have tried the following as well:

```
import subprocess
import time

binary_path = '/path/to/binary'
args = 'arguments' # arbitrary

call_str = '{} {}'.format(binary_path, args)

proc = subprocess.Popen(call_str)
time.sleep(5)
proc.terminate()
```

This code snippet works fine at terminating the program, so it's not the actual signal that's being sent to terminate that is the problem.

How can I change the code so that the subprocess can be terminated on KeyboardInterrupt?

I'm running Python 2.7 and Windows 7 64-bit. Thanks in advance!

Some related questions that I tried:

[Python sub process Ctrl+C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807134/python-sub-process-ctrlc)

[Kill subprocess.call after KeyboardInterrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496416/kill-subprocess-call-after-keyboardinterrupt)

[kill subprocess when python process is killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603658/kill-subprocess-when-python-process-is-killed)

Comment: Why not catch the ctrl-c signal in your main program and use that to call `proc.terminate()`?

Comment: In Python 3 you could use `_winapi.WaitForMultipleObjects([proc._handle], False, -1)`. For the main thread and given the wait-all flag is false, this wait automatically includes Python's `SIGINT` event. In 2.x you'd have to implement this from scratch using ctypes or PyWin32.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for the suggestion. There is a module called win32event that has a similar function and can be imported for Python 2, but I tried `win32event.WaitForMultipleObjects([proc._handle], False, -1)` and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @limi44, 3.x use a Windows Event object that gets set by the signal handler for Ctrl+C. This event gets automatically added to the list when `_winapi.WaitForMultipleObjects` is called. Implementing this in 2.x requires PyWin32 or ctypes to define a console `CTRL_C_EVENT` handler  (e.g. passing a ctypes callback function to `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`) that sets an Event (created via `CreateEvent`). You'd then wrap `WaitForMultipleObjects` to append the Ctrl+C event handle to the list and reset the event (`ResetEvent`) before waiting, but only when called from the main thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this, similar to Jean-Francois's answer with the loop but without the multiple threads. The key is to use Popen.poll() to determine if the subprocess has finished (will return None if still running).

```
import subprocess
import time

binary_path = '/path/to/binary'
args = 'arguments' # arbitrary

call_str = '{} {}'.format(binary_path, args)

proc = subprocess.Popen(call_str)

try:
    while proc.poll() is None:
        time.sleep(0.1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    proc.terminate()
    raise
```

I added an additional raise after KeyboardInterrupt so the Python program is also interrupted in addition to the subprocess.

EDIT: Changed pass to time.sleep(0.1) as per eryksun's comment to reduce CPU consumption.

Comment: `time.sleep(.1)` is interruptible. Using it instead of `pass` should reduce CPU consumption.

Answer (score 2):

My ugly but successfull attempt on Windows:

```
import subprocess
import threading

import time

binary_path = 'notepad'
args = 'foo.txt' # arbitrary

proc = None
done = False

def s():
    call_str = '{} {}'.format(binary_path, args)
    global done
    global proc
    proc = subprocess.Popen(call_str,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.wait()
    done = True


t = threading.Thread(target=s)
t.start()


try:
    while not done:
        time.sleep(0.1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("terminated")
    proc.terminate()
```

Create a thread where the subprocess runs. Export the `proc` variable.

Then wait forever in a non-active loop. When CTRL+C is pressed, the exception is triggered. Inter-process communication (ex: `proc.wait()`) is conflicting with CTRL+C handling otherwise. When running in a thread, no such issue.

note: I have tried to avoid this time loop using `threading.lock()` but stumbled on the same CTRL+C ignore.