# Python: threads and KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, multithreading

Given the following code (running under Linux)...

```
import threading
import time

def donothing(quit):
    while True:
        if quit.wait(1):
            break

    print 'quitting'

quit = threading.Event()

try:
    t = threading.Thread(target=donothing, args=(quit,))
    t.start()
    t.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'interrupt!'
    quit.set()
```

Type `^C` while the program is running will *not* generate a `KeyboardInterrupt`:

```
python example.py 
^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C
```

Adding a timeout of *any* value to `t.join()` changes this behavior.  That is, if I have instead:

```
t.join(86400)
```

Then I see (without needing to wait 86400 seconds):

```
$ python example.py 
^Cinterrupt!
quitting
```

What is going on here?  I assume that in the first case the `join` operation locks the GIL and prevents any signal handlers from running, but why does adding *any* timeout change this behavior?

I've spent a little time poking through the code, and while I'm getting lost somewhere in `Modules/_threadmodule.c` it *looks* as if the same code path is followed regardless of whether or not a timeout was specified.

Comment: same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544578/better-way-to-interrupt-my-python-code-when-subprocess-is-running. In the comments it's suggested that it's possible to break from a sleep but not from other system blocking calls.

Comment: are you running windows & unix/linux?

Comment: I'm running under Linux. I updated the question to make that explicit.  Sorry about that.